# Onedrive public sharing link disabled now?

Tags: onedrive, cloud-storage

I have been working on Onedrive filepicker API for the past one month.

It was working fine till now.

But, suddenly I found it bizarre that setting a folder public option is disabled in onedrive. This option let me share the files so that the files can be seen by anyone once it is attached in a mail or something.

I'm really sick of it.

This [documention](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/onedrive/share-file-folder) of onedrive still shows that option but it's invisible.

Is there anything wrong with Microsoft onedrive now.

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about your scenario? It sounds like in the past you used to get "public" links, but what did you do with them? Did you ignore the link itself and then get references to children of the folder and add those to emails?

Comment: Sry for the delay brad!. In the past in onedrive there is a view, edit and public links. By selecting the public link we can attach files in a forum or a mail publicly so that other viewers can view it. but for the past week I can see only view and edit link but not the public link.

Comment: without the public link, other viewers will get the error as "you are trying to access a file for which you have no permission". I don't know why onedrive changed it's options lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked the OneDrive website and I'm able to share files and folders using the following steps.

1) Go to www.onedrive.com
2) Check/select the file/folder you want to share.
3) Select "Share" from the top menu
4) Select "Get a link"
5) Choose "View Only", "Edit", or "Public"
6) Press "Get Link" button.

[image]

I signed out of my account and was able to access the folder/file links just fine without any permission issues.  Are you able to get the share link using the steps?

Comment: yes, the problem was rectified  yesterday morning. thanks for checking that.

Comment: The Get a link screen does not offer this option any more.

Answer (score 1):

See the following link:-

https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/8264673-there-is-no-option-public-shown-in-onedrive-anym

Essentially it looks like Microsoft are being arrogant and treating their users like muck. The problem was temporarily fixed before disappearing again. Looks like they may have withdrawn this feature and are not prepared to say why. Note the comments of Onedrive "Group Program Manager". If he had any decent knowledge of IT systems he would say what was going on instead of playing dumb