# How to get View shared link programmatically in Onedrive?

Tags: onedrive

In Onedrive, there is a way to create view link and edit link.

By selecting share ->  get a link -> view and a view link is generated.

I want to know is there a way I can get this link programmatically.

Comment: Since you posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737828/getting-error-with-a-http-post-request) before this one in regards to creating a view link programmatically is there something else you wanted to address with this?

Comment: My both these questions started from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717620/onedrive-public-sharing-link-disabled-now). Lately, I am seeing only view, edit links but not the public link. So, when I attach a file using Live SDK it's not accessible to other users. So, I thought  embedding this view link with the file and showing it to all other users might make them accesible.